# Is it possible to create the Y combinator in typescript at type level?

Tags: typescript, types, combinatory-logic

I've been messing around with recursive types, and I'm currently trying to create the [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator) at the type level.

Essentially, I would like a type `Y<f> = ...` where `f` is itself a type.

I've tried to adapt this lisp code:

```lisp
(define (Y f)
    ((lambda (x) (x x))
     (lambda (x) (f (x x)))))
```

I can simply create a type for `(lambda (x) (x x))` with:

```
type self_call<X> = X<X>
```

What I'm struggling with is finding a way to express `(lambda (x) (f (x x))))`. I need to pass `f` into some sort of type that creates this, but I'm not sure how to create a type that returns a custom type, or if it's even possible. I'm starting to feel like I've gone the wrong way with this.

*Is it possible to create such a `Y<f>` type, and if so, how?*

Comment: TypeScript doesn't support higher kinded types (as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)), so you *can't* "simply" write `type self_call<X> = X<X>` (well, you can, but it's an error). Even if it had those, you'd probably need *generic* kinds in order to begin to express a fixed point at the type level, and we *definitely* don't have those. I sense some other problems with your question (`Y<f>` would only make sense if `f` is a *generic* type, but you don't mention that), but I think the answer to your question as asked is just "no".